# WPF Adorner как применить в коде?

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Есть код, как его использовать?

```
public class ResizeAdorner : Adorner
    {
        public ResizeAdorner(UIElement adornedElement) : base(adornedElement)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            Rect adornedElementRect = new Rect(this.AdornedElement.DesiredSize);

            SolidColorBrush renderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            renderBrush.Opacity = 0.6;
            Pen renderPen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Navy), 1.5);
            double renderRadius = 5.0;

            drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.BottomRight, renderRadius, renderRadius);
            drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.BottomLeft, renderRadius, renderRadius);
            drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.TopRight, renderRadius, renderRadius);
            drawingContext.DrawEllipse(renderBrush, renderPen, adornedElementRect.TopLeft, renderRadius, renderRadius);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, какую задачу вы решаете, дополните вопрос.

Comment: Есть контрол (любой), как на этот контрол прикрепить adorner?